# MongoDB cannot upsert something without valid shard key

Tags: php, mongodb, sharding, mongodb-indexes

Sorry but I am new to MongoDB
I think I understand the concept of shards, and how data can be distributed across servers via a hashed shard key - however I am then unsure on how you know which shard you are to query.

For example - I have a collection of users, which is sharded, and has an index of _id_hashed (so far so good - nice evenly distributed db of users) I then need to timeout those users who have been inactive for a set time

```
    $c->update(array('session.lastLogged'=>array('$lt'=>$time - ($timeout*60))), array('$set' => array('session'=>'') ));
```

I get the following error:

```
For non-multi updates, must have _id or full shard key ({ _id: "hashed" }) in query
```

However, I do not know the id to query, and the session data will change and so cannot act as the shard key

Is this an issue with the structure of my data or with my query?

Answer (score 1):

That's just a [restriction of MongoDB sharded clusters](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#sharded-clusters). Why don't you keep the _id in the session? Or perhaps you could use the user's userId/loginId as the _id or shard key of your document.

Answer (score 1):

> however I am then unsure on how you know which shard you are to query.

The thing about hashed `_id` indexes is that they do not require you to know what shard to  query. MongoDB uses the hash to know where to place a document in a cluster but not how to query for one.

This means you can query by your normal `ObjectId` and it will automatically route to the right shard and the right document on said shard.

> I get the following error:

As said above in @helmy's answer: you require either the shard key or the `_id` of a document due to restrictions (basically how can it know otherwise?).

Since you are in fact trying to update ALL users I would instead just add:

```
array('multiple' => true)
```

To your query.

It will however do a scatter and gather operation, in other words it will go out to all shards and ask for the result and then act upon that result. Something to bare in mind there.